# Is it possible to get pdf page using pyppeteer?

Tags: python, pyppeteer

```
import asyncio
import pyppeteer
import logging
from pyppeteer import launch

pyppeteer.DEBUG = True
for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict:
    logging.getLogger(name).disabled = True

async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless = False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(True)
    response = await page.goto('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf',
                                time = 3000, waitUntil = ['domcontentloaded', 'load', 'networkidle0'])
    content = await response.buffer()
    print(content)
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

expected output: content of http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

got output: b'df48fcc4-a0b0-4e86-b52e-0ec012ee791e'

Python 3,Linux Ubuntu

Comment: I’ve been trying at this for hours with no success, definite lack of documentation in this area. I was able to replicate the intended response using python requests and simply parsing the response body as text, which may be a lot easier as a workaround if shit hits the fan.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just use `requests`?

Comment: This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665650/how-to-obtain-a-pdf-embedded-in-page-through-puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [pyppdf](https://github.com/kiwi0fruit/pyppdf) it's a Python port of the Puppeteer.

```
conda install -c defaults -c conda-forge pyppdf
OR
pip install pyppdf
```

it has a handy function `save_pdf`

> ```py
> def save_pdf(output_file: str=None, url: str=None, html: str=None,
>             args_dict: Union[str, dict]=None,
>             args_upd: Union[str, dict]=None,
>             goto: str=None, dir_: str=None) -> bytes:
> ```

or you could simply just

```py
await page.screenshot({'path': 'ss.png'})
await page.pdf({'path': 'sample.pdf'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that you are asking for a solution using **pyppeteer**, but honestly this can be done way easier with **requests**.

```py
import requests


def main():
    r = requests.get("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf")
    with open("sample.pdf", "wb") as file:
        file.write(r.content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

That's all your file will be saved in a file called `sample.pdf`.